# Is this book answer wrong?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, education

I came across this simplification exercise which tells us to simplify:
$\frac{\sqrt{8} - \sqrt{16}}{4 - \sqrt{2}} - 2^{1/2}$.

The answer in the book is $\frac{-5\sqrt{2} -6}{7}$.

I'm getting close but not to this answer, wondering if it's correct.

Thanks in advance, I tried alot of resources to solve this, maybe someone knows what's up.

Comment: In general when dealing with fractions and radicals, try to get a common denominator, or rationalize the denominator.

Comment: This is correct

Comment: Often, when you doubt the book, you can plug the original expression in a calculator and get a decimal for it.  Do the same with the answer and see if you get the same decimal.  If the answer in the back is wrong, then you'll find out right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\frac{2\sqrt{2}-4}{4-\sqrt{2}}-\sqrt{2}=\\
\frac{2\sqrt{2}-4}{4-\sqrt{2}}\cdot \frac{4+\sqrt{2}}{4+\sqrt{2}}-\sqrt{2}=\\
\frac{8\sqrt{2}-16+4-4\sqrt{2}}{16-2}-\sqrt{2}=\\
\frac{4\sqrt{2}-12}{14}-\sqrt{2}=\\
\frac{2\sqrt{2}-6}{7}-\sqrt{2}=\\
\frac{2\sqrt{2}-6-7\sqrt{2}}{7}=\\
\frac{-5\sqrt{2}-6}{7}
$$

Comment: Hey thanks, how did you put the minus squareroot(2) into the division?

Comment: Well, common denominator

Comment: Could you elaborate on that ?

Comment: $\frac{a}{b}+c=\frac{a+bc}{b}$. In this case $b=7$ and $c=-\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Thanks I forgot that (or didn't know), I can apply it now, thanks.